# HTML async load image is still very slow

Tags: javascript, html, flask, jinja2

Im using html's built in lazy loading and async decoding however the page still takes a full minute to load. how could I make the images load asynchronously to the page so the page will load faster?

```
{% if limiteds is not none %}
    {% for limited in limiteds %}
    <div class="card">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ limited[3] }}" loading="lazy" decoding="async" style="width:60px; height:60px">
        <h5 class="card-title">{{ limited[0] }}</h5>
        <p class="card-text">R$ {{ limited[1] }}</p>
        <p class="card-text">$ {{ limited[2] }}</p>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Thanks in advance,

- JoshMann15

Comment: Your question is more generic. First of all you have to make sure, It is the image taking too long to load, or the page itself. If it is just the image, Make sure you are loading the correct and necessary resolution of the image, loading the image locally instead of the public URL and the browser caches the image for later usage.

Comment: Thanks for the response @BadPiggie . I have confirmed the page takes around 5s to load and the images then add an additional minute to that time. as the images are often different loading them to browser cash doesn't make much sense. would there be any way for them to load independently to the web page?

Comment: There's nothing you can do in your HTML code to make image loading faster. If it's very slow, that's a network problem or a server problem.